# How to implement collecting nodes according the logic

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am struggeling with xslt the last couple of weeks with a task I should implement since I have a lack an experience in xslt programming I appreciate every help I could get in solving my task, I have alredy asked a couple of questions about this task but still I have not it solved completely.
My task is to implement such code with style sheet on the basis of html data structure.

[image]

Furthermore I add mine html file:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>example_2</h1>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>global_structure in a code_1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>global_structure in a code_2</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>name of the file</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td>text_var</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>funktion</td>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>funktion</td>
            <td>A2</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>var</td>
            <td>A2_var</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>funktion</td>
            <td>A3</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>var</td>
            <td>A3_var1</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>var</td>
            <td>A3_var2</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>name of the file_2</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td>text_var</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>funktion</td>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>funktion</td>
            <td>A2</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>var</td>
            <td>A2_var</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>funktion</td>
            <td>A3</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>var</td>
            <td>A3_var1</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>skip</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>var</td>
            <td>A3_var2</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>end</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

For example file with file name: "name of the file" should have the following code

```
global_structure in a code_1(){
text;
};

global_structure in a code_2(){
A1();
A2(A2_var);
A3(A3_var1,A3_var2);
};
```

The idea is that if  the parser face any "var" it should insert it into "function". If after funktion no vars are showed funktion should be inserted without any variables. 
I have problems with that I have already asked I question how to calculate the number of rows which are between the files (skip-sequences). But I cannot undertand how can I use this function for any recursive function because it gives me two numbers as they are. Now for each iteration of my structure. Please give me any advices how to implement it. I am very new at xslt:)

Here is my link to code:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwe3c5/54

```
 <xsl:template match="/html/body/table">

   <xsl:param name ="counter_var" select="mf:skip-sequences(.)" />

   <!--name of the file-->
   <xsl:for-each select="./tr">
       <xsl:if test = "not(child::td[1] ='skip') or not(string(child::td[1]))">
           <xsl:variable name ="new_file_name" select="child::td[1]" />

             <xsl:value-of select="child::td[1]"/>
             <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
       </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>


   <!--global_structure in a code-->
   <xsl:for-each select="./tr[1]/td">

       <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="position() mod 2=0">
           <xsl:call-template name="filtering_a_position">
           <xsl:with-param name="position" select="position()">
           </xsl:with-param>
           </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:when>
     </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>




    <xsl:template name="filtering_a_position">

    <xsl:param name="position"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;xsl:value-of select="../td[$position]"&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="../td[$position]"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="/html/body/table/tr/td[$position+1]">
    <xsl:value-of select="current()"/> <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>



    </xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="mf:skip-sequences" as="xs:integer*">
     <xsl:param name="table" as="element(table)"/>
     <xsl:for-each-group select="$table/tr" group-adjacent="boolean(self::tr[td[1] = 'skip'])">
         <xsl:sequence select="count(current-group())[current-grouping-key()]"/>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:function>

 <xsl:template match="table">
     <xsl:sequence select="mf:skip-sequences(.)"/>
 </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a complex problem, and certainly will take more than the five minutes I usually allow myself for a StackOverflow answer. But it feels very much to me like the kind of problem that will benefit from a multi-phase approach: that is, divide it up into a series of transformations, each of which is relatively simple.

I would start by defining an intermediate representation of the data that reflects its logical structure. This might look something like this:

```
<files>
  <file name="file1">
    <structure in="code1">
      <entry type="text_var" name="text"/>
    </structure>
    <structure in="code2">
      <entry type="funktion" name="A1"/>
      <entry type="funktion" name="A2"/>
      <entry type="var" name="A2_var"/>
      ... etc ...
```

(I might have got this wrong; I don't claim to understand your data or its true structure).

The first stage of the transformation (to get to this structure from your initial input) can be done using `<xsl:for-each-group select="tr" group-starting-with="tr[td[1] ne 'skip']">`.

The second stage also involves positional grouping, this time something like `<xsl:for-each-group select="entry" group-starting-with="entry[@type='funktion'">`.

I know this is only a sketch of an approach to a solution, but I hope it takes you forward.